# Excel VBA - how to automatically correspond ranges to value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

how are you all today?

I am in need to perform a function (Excel or VBA) in over 2000 entries and I can't seem to figure it out.

*Example:*

```
Sheet 1 - Column A (Dog, Cat, Lion, Eagle, Falcon, Vulture, Shark, Seabass, Whale)
    
Sheet 1 - Column B (Land, Air, Sea)
    
New sheet - Column A - new entries
    
New sheet - Column B - automatically filled cells with the corresponding element
```

I need an automatic way to:

1. Match each animal to an element

> `Dog, Cat, Lion = Land`; `Falcon, Vulture, Eagle = Air`; `Shark, Seabbas, Whale = Sea`.

*This example is doable one-by-one but I have over 2000 entries to do it manually. I need a way to select a range in column A that corresponds to a specific cell in column B.*

2. Create a result table (new sheet) with the populated column A with the pre-determined values in *Sheet 1 - Column A* and a new column with the corresponding elements.

   `new sheet = column A (entry column) and column B (correspondence column)`

Hope I made it clear... I guess this may be a little bit confusing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Construct a `VLOOKUP()` table

Comment: Simple answer for a simple need. I will give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: Some diagrams or screen shots of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: I solved it, with a bit of work, with a VLOOKUP table in a different document. This way it will be my future reference. Thanks for your help.