# EXCEL how to check the correspondance one column value to another (adjacent)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to check which value in the adjacent row corresponds to my column.
I tried to use the VLOOKUP function as follows:

[Excel VBA - how to automatically correspond ranges to value](https://superuser.com/questions/1322049/excel-vba-how-to-automatically-correspond-ranges-to-value)

but with no results.

If you look at my picture below:
[image]

I am interested in column F (Postcode) and G (Key).
Each postcode corresponds to the specified key. Because they were repeatable I did a separate list, calculating all of them manually.
Now I would like to assign a proper postcode to each key mentioned in this list (column M).
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I am taking your commentary and the fact cell M8 has a value exactly the same as G2 to mean the list in column M is composed of values that match something in column G. (Actually, that's pretty necessary, considering, but also pretty implied.)

So, a problem made for `XLOOKUP()` or the ability of the hoary `INDEX/MATCH` combo to "look left."

For the `XLOOKUP()`, the `lookup_value` will be the values in column M. The `lookup_array` will be column G. The `return_array` will be column F. The rest of its options are up to you, of course, but exact matches ARE expected so that fact should control that choice. I'll just worry about these three:

```
=XKLOOKUP(M2,G:G,F:F)
```

and modify those values to best suit the extent of your data:  Searching just 200 cells is faster than searching a million, people would say, though Excel quits when finding a match so... a column reference isn't the end of the world. Well... so long as nothing else lives in that column. (People do that, sadly.)

If they don't match perfectly, you might still be able to match things up depenbding upon the details of "don't match perfectly." Perhaps the whole phrase in column M is in column G's material so a wildcard search can work. `XLOOKUP()` can do that. If the values in column M are just the start of the column G values, or sometimes the whole thing, just not always, the "Exact match or next HIGHER item" parameter could do wonders.

However, if words or characters are dropped from inside the phrases, even creativity with the wildcard option might not help, especially if it was not done in some consistent, understandable (and known) way.

Fill down in column L with the formula and you have your result.

Sorry, forgot to mention (ahh, the good NEW old days!), most of the above can be achieved using the `INDEX/MATCH` combo which can be found on ten thousand websites. It's probably on your matress's label.

Comment: it doesn't work unfortunately. I am getting #NAME instead.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the formula should look like this:

```
=INDEX(F:F,MATCH(M2,G:G,0))
```

https://exceljet.net/index-and-match